# CASE WHEN multiple condition, works only after another one removed

Tags: mysql, case, case-when

I got shocked when I found the conflict between following two conditions.

I tried and checked with many ways, but later, I have found that the last `WHEN` condition works only **if first one is removed**.

```
CASE
    WHEN
        (@cid != '0' OR @cid != '') AND @ftm != '0' AND (@sid != '' OR @sid != '0')
    THEN 
        cls.id = @cid AND fee_tm.id = @ftm AND sec.id = @sid
    WHEN
        (@cid != '0' OR @cid != '') AND @ftm != '0' AND (@sid = '0') AND
    THEN
        cls.id = @cid AND fee_tm.id = @ftm
END
```

Here `@cid` is related with **cls.id**, `@ftm` with **fee_time.id** and `@sid` with **sec.id**

**To be more clearer and specific**,

```
value `0` means All:

@cid = 0 (All classes),
@sid = 0 (All Sections),
@ftm = 0 (All fee_tm)

value '' (empty) means nothing is selected.
value != 0 and value != '' means user input.
```

**First `WHEN` condition is for:**

if `@cid`(class.id), `@ftm`(fee_time.id), `@sid`(sec.id), none of them are not empty nor All

**Second `WHEN` condition is for:**

if `@cid`(class.id), `@ftm`(fee_time.id), none of these two are not empty nor all (matched with first condtion) - but difference is: if `@sid`(sec.id) is 0 (All).

I tried to combine both condition in one condition but can't adjust. However it should work, shouldn't it?

My **MYSQL CODE** `WHERE` Clause is as below

```
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN
            @cid = '0' AND @sid = '0' AND @ftm ='0'
        THEN
            cls.id
        WHEN
            @cid = '0' AND @sid = '0' AND @ftm !='0'
        THEN
            fee_tm.id=@ftm
        WHEN
            (@cid !='0' OR @cid !='') AND (@sid !='' OR @sid !='0') AND @ftm !='0'
        THEN
            cls.id=@cid AND sec.id =@sid AND fee_tm.id =@ftm
        WHEN
            (@cid !='0' OR @cid !='') AND (@sid='0') AND @ftm !='0'
        THEN
            cls.id=@cid AND fee_tm.id=@ftm
    END
GROUP BY
    student.id, inv_id.ft_id, cls.id
```

Comment: Let's say your first `WHEN` condition fires.  `WHERE cls.id` makes no sense, in general.  Also, `WHERE fee_tm.id = @ftm` makes no sense either.  You should show us sample data and the expected output here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I was studying your previous answer and comparing with my `CASE` condition, and started to re-structure my code with your guidelines. So I am late to response, but I found It has been already removed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks man !!! realized, unnecessarily usage of `CASE`, solved easily with `And` and `OR`.

Comment: @AnandHmt if the query is resolved. Post the final solution you figure out and mark as answer for closure.